# Javascript validate user input against desired character set (encoding)

Tags: javascript, validation, character-encoding

The scenario is as follows:

User copies text from web site using Win-1252 encoding for its character set.  This text is then sent to a database that I control with a character set of ISO-8859-1(this is a subset of Win-1252).  Is there a mechanism within Javascript to inform the user that they are trying to insert "invalid" characters into the system?  Preference if it can highlight said characters.

The general form of this problem is that a system A(sending system) has a Set of encodings defined as `AsubE`  and a different system B(the accepting system) has a set of encodings defined as `BsubE`.  When `BsubE` is inside the universe of `AsubE` it is not a problem.  The question is about when `BsubE` is not a subset of `AsubE` how can we validate the input from the user.

Comment: If you control the database, why not set the database you control to use something like UTF-8? Then anything the user gives you is fine.

Comment: @Anthony For the sake of this question let's just say I can't/won't

Answer (score 3):

Since some characters are not defined in the subset, you could use a regular expression to define those intervals:

```
function isNotAllowed(char) {
    return /\x00-\x1f|\x7f-\x9f/.test(char); // 00 to 1f, or 7f to 9f
}
```

To also highlight characters it will become more complicated but this function could be the core of it.

Comment: Interesting, so if I take the characters that I know based on my db I could place those inside the return function and anything that doesn't match would function?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I'm sorry, could you rephrase your question please?

Comment: sorry I blacked out there.  That function looks for a range of unicode values that I do not accept.  Therefore if I change the values to ones that I do accept I could write it as a not statement.   As in `return ![rangeOfChars]`

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Yes, if you put a `!` before that first `/` it will simply invert the boolean result. (As in `isAllowed` and then the same function except a `!` prepended.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no facility in JavaScript to do this. Luckily, neither Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 is a variable-width encoding, so you could write something in, say, .NET or something that does understand character encodings to make a regular expression to test this.

For instance, in .NET, you could make a byte array with 256 bytes, one for each character, and then use each encoding to get the appropriate string. Figure out the differences in those strings, encode them into a regular expression, and there you go.

Comment: I suppose I could just regex match against `p{InBasic_Latin}`  and whatever doesn't match remove